# Can I save some steps when burning same playlist over and over?

Tags: itunes, cd-burning

iMac OSX 10.8.5

I am often producing demo CDs for a musician.

The steps are

1. insert blank
2. scroll to playlist
3. right click and choose burn
4. click ok
5. wait for jingle - this scrolls to the playable CD
6. click eject

repeat

I would like to

1. scroll to playlist ONCE
2. right click and choose burn
3. get prompted for disks until I am done and click cancel

Is there a setting I did not find? I am not interested in 3rd party software - just wondering if there is a setting I overlooked or perhaps some way of automating this.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider buying Toast from Roxio there's a light version on the AppStore that still allows you to choose the numbers of copies...

Comment: Thanks, but I was not planning to purchase anything  I was just wondering if there was something I had overlooked.

Comment: I don't think so what you may do is in the Keyboard System Preferences a shortcut to access the menu item more easily... E.g. click the playlist then each CD hit the keystroke(s) you have created...

Comment: The issue is that the playlist is deselected each time. I think I'm SOL